# PHP fopen () function failed to open and permission denied

Tags: php

Am using XAMP 1.7.3
on Macbook pro osx 10.9
Firefox browser

Well basically i am trying to write a code asking the user to enter some information and then store the information in a .txt file using the:

```
 $txtfile="registration.txt";
 $handle=fopen($txtfile,'a');
```

But I keep getting the this error message :

> Warning: fopen(registration.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/UserInfoAhmed.php on line 30
>
> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/UserInfoAhmed.php on line 31
>
> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/UserInfoAhmed.php on line 32
>
> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/UserInfoAhmed.php on line 33
>
> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/UserInfoAhmed.php on line 34
>
> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/UserInfoAhmed.php on line 35

full code is :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Informations</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="">
    Name    : <input type="text" name="name"/> <br>
    Age     : <input type="text" name="age"/> <br>
    City    : <input type="text" name="city"/> <br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pswrd1"/> <br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pswrd2"/> <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value"send"/>
    <form/>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $name=$_POST["name"];
        $age=$_POST["age"];
        $city=$_POST["city"];
        $pswrd1=$_POST["pswrd1"];
        $pswrd2=$_POST["pswrd2"];

        if($pswrd1 == $pswrd2){
            if($city==dubai){
                if($age>18){
                    $txtfile="registration.txt";
                    $handle=fopen($txtfile,'a');
                    fwrite($handle, $name);
                    fwrite($handle, $age);
                    fwrite($handle, $city);
                    fwrite($handle, $pswrd1);
                    fwrite($handle,$pswrd2);                    
                }
                else echo "age must be > 18";
            }
            else echo "city must be dubai";
        }
        else echo "password must identical";
        echo "<br>";



    }

    ?>
</body>
```

first i understood the first error message, failure to access / create the .txt file, and as i searched in this website, several ppl had the same problem, some the suggested a permission problem with the main file, and since every time i try to update the php file i get asked to enter my admin password, so i assumed the XAMP main file also protected

i changed the file option to read & write by all users, and all the folders within the main XAMP folder. but still i get asked for the password to save any changes in the php file am writing this code in, and thus i guess am still getting the same :
fopen(registration.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...

so how could i fix this ? 
also am wondering if the rest of error messages related to the main problem ?

all in all, could someone tell me at least if there is a mistake in my code ?

Comment: Did you checked your permission to the folder /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/

Comment: yes i did check my permission on each of these folders and changed it to Read & Write.

Comment: Change your permission to 777.

Comment: i tried sudo chmod 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/registration.txt, but same result ?

Answer (score 1):

**First**

Try to set registration.txt permissions via console:

```
sudo chmod 0777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/registration.txt
```

**Second**

If first didn't work then I think that you should change your htdocs folder location, because when it's in Applications folder it might not work properly because Applications folder might be somehow protected by system.

Edit your XAMPP apache httpd.conf and set DocumentRoot to /users/USERNAME/Documents/htdocs

Be sure to create htdocs folder under your Documents folder.

Then in console change folder permissions:

```
sudo chmod 0777 /users/USERNAME/Documents/htdocs
```

Then try to put some random file in the folder and try to open it in browser

```
http://localhost/randomfile.php
```

It should work. If you are getting internal server error (500) then comment out following line in httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so
```

Comment: Well, i've tried your first suggestion: setting registration.txt permissions via console, but it didnt work, so i tried your second suggestion and followed your steps, and every time i try to view the .php file in the new htdocs folder under Documents it wont show it up, actually it would still be showing files from the original htdocs in xamp folder ?

Comment: 0777. Read, Write & Execute permission? No, please don't.