# Can't write over files

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, fclose, shred

I am trying to code a file shredder in PHP, and I get these errors:

> Warning: fopen(calculate): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\shred.php on line 9
>   Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\shred.php on line 11

```
<?PHP
$files = glob("*");

foreach ($files as $files) {
    $size = filesize($files);
    $bytes = "1";
    $writes = "1";
    while ($writes <= "3") {
    $data = fopen($files, "w");
        while ($bytes <= $size) {
            fwrite($files, "0");
            $bytes = $bytes + 1;
        }
    fclose($data);
    $writes = $writes + 1;  
    }
    //  unlink($files);
}
?>
```

I have no idea what to do at this point. The files aren't read only.

Comment: `foreach ($files as $files)`, shouldn't this be foreach `($files as $file)`?

Comment: `foreach ($files as $files)` may be wrong perhaps? try `foreach ($files as $file)`

Comment: I can see how that was ambiguos i edited the comment

Comment: Changing that won't work, it just does what is in the foreach for every file in that directory, I use the same code for something else.

Comment: @Hypothermia it's still a good idea to avoid ambiguity and make your code more readable. Typically any variable in plural form is likely an array. So `$files` should be an array of files and use `$file` when dealing with a single file.

Comment: @Mike True. I will be cleaning it up after it's done, though.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `$data` as the first parameter of `fwrite`.

Comment: Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\shred.php on line 12

That's now the second error.

Comment: Yea that is probably beacuse of the first error you're getting. The first error to sum it up, means that the script you're running doesn't have access to write to the file, you're trying to opening. Therefore the fopen returns false and since you don't have any controls, the false statement goes into the fwrite. I don't have any  knowledge on how to give your script acesss to editing files. You should search for it on the google.

Comment: I'll look into it. It deletes all files, but no folders. Maybe I could drop the php file in each directory and run it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the appropriate permissions because that is the common problem in using

> fopen()

you can see the the same errors with this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652760/php-fopen-function-failed-to-open-and-permission-denied).