# PHP permissions denied failed to open stream

Tags: php

I have this code

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen('names.rtf','w');
    fwrite($handle, 'Alex');
?>
```

> Warning: fopen(names.rtf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/file.php on line 3

And when I run it in comes up with that error. I've set my permissions on the folder to read & write for everyone. I'm not sure why else it would deny it.

Im using the latest Mac OS

Comment: Maybe the file is opened by another process which is locking it?

Comment: I've closed all the other processes and this error still occurs

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652760/php-fopen-function-failed-to-open-and-permission-denied

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is possible, the issue is that your webserver or PHP instance is not running under the same user, you can check this using the [**get_current_user()**](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php) function.

You can either configure apache to run with your privileges or give the folder more permissions, like **0777**.but `0644` is enough for reading file. try to give permission according to it's usage.

Another thing, are you sure $outFile maps to an absolute path? Try doing:

```
var_dump(is_file("names.rtf"));
```

Comment: Wait. Absolutely incorrect! This poses **security threat** as you add **execute** permission to files.

Comment: but he know about this it is his responsibility to set permission to files.i only suggest the way.

Comment: ya of curse but i saw the way only.